# IBM Mobilefirst migration to v8.0 - user migration

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We have a mobile apps running on v7.1. And now we want to migrate to v8.0. I have read the migration cookbook, however it does not seem to explain the following:

How to migrate the existing user? The user has already subscribe to push-notification. I believe the information are stored in mobile first database, and I read from [this](http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/upgrading/#changes-in-the-server-databases-and-in-the-server-structure)  it does not have a script to migrate the database.

How do we keep the existing user information? So, the migration process will require 2 versions running in parallel and slowly move the user to the new version? It seems that we cannot “upgrade” the old server to the new version, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot migrate the user information from MFP 7.x to 8.0 as the security architecture is completely different between these versions.

Comment: What is the best practice to keep user's information?